# I'm trying to find a file size. But my length is equl to zero

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, nsfilehandle

I'm trying to find a file size.

```
 NSFileHandle *output = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:self.finalPath]; 
//seek to begin of the file
[output seekToFileOffset:0];
NSData *mydata = [output availableData];
NSLog(@"length: %d", [mydata length]);
```

But my length is equl to zero. Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`availableData` is for reading files. If you just want to find out the size of a file, you don't actually have to open it. Just use `NSFileManager` like this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:self.finalPath error:NULL];
unsigned long long fileSize = [attributes fileSize]; // in bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

[fileHandler seekToEndOfFile], this returns the length of your file data, your code [output seekToFileOffset:0] means from 0-0,so there is no data