# iOS - Swift How do i know when copyItemAtPath has been finished?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I want to create pre-seed database at the beginning
The file is quite large (5mb).

I use `copyItemAtPath` to copy files, so do this method has completion?
How do i know when this process has been finished?

Comment: The copy is done when the copyItemAtPath method returns, it is not asynchronous. How else could it report a failure by throwing an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is enough:

```
do {
    // copy files from main bundle to documents directory
    print("copy")
    try 
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(sourcePath, toPath: destinationPath)
} catch let error as NSError {
     // Catch fires here, with an NSError being thrown
     print("error occurred, here are the details:\n \(error)")
}
```

where destinationPath can be for example:

```
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first
```

Answer (score 0):

From [How to show the progress of copying a large file in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414802/how-to-show-the-progress-of-copying-a-large-file-in-ios)

> 1. Run your copying process in a seperate thread (T1)
> 2. Run another thread (T2) which reads periodically (say every 100ms)
>      the destination file current_size.
> 3. Calculate the percentage to display progress: current_size / total_size